# Where do we get “queen” from?

Tags: etymology, history, old-english, early-modern-english

*King* comes from Old Norse *konungr*, and *prince* is from French *principle*, but I have found no definite etymology for *queen* as we know it. I have found assumptive connections such as to *keenan* and *gna*, but nothing definite.

Is there any definitive etymology on *queen?

Comment: It comes from the PIE root [_*gʷen-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080627204018/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE182.html).

Comment: Interestingly, in my native language Armenian, the same word has evolved to mean woman. կին /kin/

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Do you know whether this a "co-incidence" or do the English and Armenian have a common forebear? I have read somewhere (no reference, sorry) that the Moroccan Arabic word for "dog" is, by pure co-incidence, "dog". Or witness Japanese "so desu ka!" and other Japanese uses of "so" so like those in English and, of course, wholly co-incidental.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Unlike Japanese or Arabic, Armenian is an Indo-European language, albeit a separate group. There are very many words in Armenian that come from PIE, including կին.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary online's first few lines of the etymology of queen are as follows:

> Cognate with Old Saxon quān wife, Old Icelandic kván wife, (in poetry)
>   queen (also as kvæn ), Gothic qens woman < an ablaut variant
>   (lengthened grade) of the Indo-European base of quean n.; compare
>   Sanskrit jāni wife.
>
> In Old English a strong feminine, the reflex of the genitive singular
>   of which (Old English cwēne ) occas. survives into early Middle
>   English (compare quene in quot. c1325 at sense 2), although levelling
>   of the genitive singular in -es is found as early as the first half of
>   the 12th cent. (compare quot. lOE2 at sense 2).

My ling professor says the OED online is pretty much the definitive source for etymology of the English language. However you will have to have an account I believe to access the website. I would think most universities have accounts.

"queen, n.". OED Online. December 2012. Oxford University Press. 7 February 2013 http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156212?rskey=0XwDuT&result=1&isAdvanced=false.